Retrieving Test Devices for RCS Agent
I am currently working with the RCS Business Messaging API and would like to know how to retrieve a list of test devices (or testers) associated with a specific RCS agent.
Specifically, I am trying to find an endpoint or method that allows me to view the devices that have been registered as test devices for a particular agent.
Could you provide guidance on the following:
Is there an API endpoint available to retrieve a list of test devices or testers associated with an agent ID?
What is the correct format for making this request, if such an endpoint exists?
Are there any restrictions or requirements for retrieving this information (e.g., specific roles or permissions needed)?
Any clarification or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
